# Avoid from loading scripts on Fire Fox version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frontend

I modified few web pages . All works fine on all browsers except Firefox version 3.6.24 on Linux Open SUSE.Problem with scripts file where I used jQuery.
Can I avoid on HTML file loading specific scripts when system will detect that browser is Firefox version 3.6.24 ?
Something like on IE 

    ...

Comment: Are you really using Firerfox (one word) version 3? Considering that the current version is 53?

Comment: Sadly to say you but yes :( . I haven't choice and can't upgrade it.